# Is there a way to use *.localhost as hostnames with docker when building complex apps like Next/Nuxt

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, nuxt.js

So I'm trying to setup a Docker environment using the ***.localhost** format (**front.localhost** and **sdk.localhost** for example), which is automatically recognized by browsers as pointing to 127.0.0.1 and doesn't need a manual host modification.

Although my problem is the following:
**front.localhost** is a Next/Nuxt app, and it needs to be able to call **sdk.localhost** both directly from the browser (which works fine) but also from the backend in the container. But when the **front.localhost** container tries to reach the **sdk.localhost** container it doesn't work because it interprets **sdk.localhost** as 127.0.0.1 and never reach the other container.

Is there a way to tell docker containers to not interpret ***.localhost** as 127.0.0.1 but as another container hostname in the same network?

It is obvious I guess, but I cannot use a different hostname to call the container internally, because the API call is the same code for reaching from the browser as from reaching from the backend.

I've tried a lot of things like: aliases, external_links, multiple networks, but nothing worked for me. I also tried to setup a reverse proxy with Traefik but it didn't help. I cannot manage to make a container reach another container who is exposed with a ***.locahost** hostname.

I realize this may not be very clear, please give me feedbacks and I'll rewrite as necessary to make it more understandable.

Reproduction example from Hans Killian:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    image: debian
    command: tail -f /dev/null

  backend:
    image: debian
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - backend.localhost
```

From the frontend container:

```
root@1aa125e575eb:/# ping backend.localhost
PING backend.localhost (172.18.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

```
root@1aa125e575eb:/# curl -v backend.localhost
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying [::1]:80...
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address
* Failed to connect to backend.localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to backend.localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: Your question has a better chance of getting a good answer if you include a minimal, reproducible example, that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I've added your example ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should allow your frontend to be configured with the address of the backend using an environment variable.

Like this compose file, where you have 2 environment variables: `BROWSER_BACKEND_HOST` for the address you use for the code that executes in the user's browser. And `CONTAINER_BACKEND_HOST` for the code that executes in the frontend container:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    image: debian
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    environment:
      - BROWSER_BACKEND_HOST=backend.localhost
      - CONTAINER_BACKEND_HOST=backend

  backend:
    image: debian
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

Then, in your container, you'd use the hostname `backend` and in the browser you'd use `backend.localhost`.

Ofc, you need to adapt your frontend code to use these variables.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to do but it doesn't work. If you "ping backend.localhost" from the frontend container you get the IP of the backend container alright, but if you try to "curl -v backend.localhost" from the frontend container you get 127.0.0.1 :(

Comment: Apparently, curl's behavior is the recommended behavior. So you should change your frontend, so you can configure the addresses used as outlined in the last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Actually I didn't fully understand the last part of your answer, please could you detail it a bit more and maybe give an example with the same frontend/backend architecture you presented?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use environment variables

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean, but I don't think environment variables are possible with these framework (Next/Nuxt), because the API URL is only defined once in the code and should work both from the browser and backend. I don't think I'm supposed to add code to detect if I'm calling from a browser or from the backend... Here is an exemple of the code in my Next app:

const sdkConfig = {
  commerce: buildModule<BoilerplateModuleType>(boilerplateModule, {
    apiUrl: 'http://sdk-localhost:8181/boilerplate',
  }),
};